# bootstrap-select is flashbacked,i used django and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-selectpicker

html error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')**

$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
i try to and JS to my code but is useless

css/js

```
<html lang="zh-cn">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="{% static 'assets/img/VPC.png' %}">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'assets/img/VPC.png' %}">
  <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Nucleo Icons -->
  <link href="{% static 'assets/css/nucleo-icons.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="{% static 'assets/css/nucleo-svg.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/42d5adcbca.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="{% static 'assets/css/nucleo-svg.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- CSS Files -->
  <link id="pagestyle" href="{% static 'assets/css/argon-dashboard.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- select -->
{#  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vanilla-select/dist/vanilla-select.min.css' %}">#}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">


  <script src="{% static 'bootstrapselect/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="{% static 'assets/js/core/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'assets/js/plugins/smooth-scrollbar.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'assets/js/plugins/chartjs.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>

  <!-- Control Center for Soft Dashboard: parallax effects, scripts for the example pages etc -->
  <script src="{% static 'assets/js/argon-dashboard.min.js' %}"></script>
  <!-- select -->
{#  <script src="{% static 'vanilla-select/dist/vanilla-select.min.js' %}"></script>#}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta2/dist/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
```

code

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker " name="AddFormat" id="AddFormat">
                            <option>Network(A.B.C.D/XX)</option>
                            <option>List</option>
                    </select>
```